# How to hide API key endpoint in release APK in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, rest

**I had put my API key endpoint in .env file. But when release APK is built the API is exposed using** `String app.apk | grep "http"` command. **Please help if I had to go for the further steps or not**
[image]

Comment: You might get them from server-side

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include API keys in your APK, then some kind of obfuscation of the env variable names and the keys (convert keys to non-printable encoding) is you best chance.

If you app includes some kind of enrollment with a remote server, the app can receive the keys during enrollment and then [securely store](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage) them on the device.

Comment: I have no backend in this app . So,what to do ??